# Add one attributes from a Collection of Objects to another Collection

Tags: java, object, arraylist, collections, iterator

Considering the following model class:

```
class A{
    String a;
    int b;
}
```

I am using it as a parameter in one of my methods like:

```
 class B{
      public static ArrayList<String> listOfAs;
      public void abc(Collection<A> collectionOfA){
      //I want a best way to create a collection of attribute 'a'.
      // I want listOfAs to be populated with the collection of a
      }
 }
```

If iterating over collectionOfA can be skipped, that would be great! Thanks

Comment: "If iterating over collectionOfA can be skipped" How do you think you could avoid that? How can you get all the `a` values from the collection of `A`s without looking at all the `A`s?

Comment: I agree @Andy Turner, I wanted to get to a best and efficient way to accomplish that. Turns out whether we use streams or any other method, the complexity will be same.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid skipping explicitly with stream but under the hood it iterates of course :

```
listOfAs = collectionOfA.stream().map(A::getA).collect(toList());
```

Note that it requires to define a public `String getA()` method and to define a `List` rather than an `ArrayList` for the field, which is a good practice.

If you really need to keep `ArrayList` as declared field you could still do :

```
listOfAs = collectionOfA.stream().map(A::getA).collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new);
```

Note that if the List should be updated and not just overwritten you could use `addAll()` :

```
List<String> list = collectionOfA.stream().map(A::getA).collect(toList());
listOfAs.addAll(list);
```

Comment: "Note that it requires" but you could just write `e -> e.a` instead of `A::getA`.

Comment: Right if A and B are in the same package. According to the posted code, it could be the case but I am wary about private package modifier used in the question sample code

Comment: Would B be able to access A if they weren't in the same package?